# Understanding the od utility output in regards to floats 'od -t f'

Tags: floating-point, od

I am making my own od utility based on the Single UNIX Specification and I am confused on how the representation of floats is handled e.g. `od -t f`. 
I have a perfectly functioning utility otherwise that is able to handle every other portion of the specification also this is not a programming question but a question on the meaning of the output when dumping as a float.

For example if I execute the following program supplying to stdin the ASCII characters **A\n** i get the following:

```
$ od -A n -t fD -
               1.297e-320
```

If I just supply **A**

```
$ od -A n -t fD -
                 3.2e-322
```

I know the value for the A and newline characters are 65 and 10 respectively  so I have no clue what these exponentially small numbers mean in the context. The specification does not give much coverage to floats so I would appreciate any information on this point.

Comment: Note that `-f` isn't mentioned in the [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/od.html), and on some implementations (eg. [GNU coreutils](https://linux.die.net/man/1/od)), it is equivalent to `-t fF`, ignoring the `D`.

Comment: Very true. Im not sure why I did not use the '-t' flag in the example as I did in the title. As it was I do not think it would have run as '-D' is not an option flag in any impliementation as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

On little-endian systems, this is the result of the representation of strings, floats, and doubles in memory. Starting with “A”, 65, or 0x41, as a float (`od -t fF`) this corresponds to

```
00000000000000000000000001000001
```

which is 9.1⋅10<sup>-44</sup> (see [this handy converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)) — a 0 bit for the sign (positive), 0 exponent (which is biased, by -126 for a float), and a fraction, 2<sup>-17</sup> + 2<sup>-23</sup>. The represented value is thus (2<sup>-17</sup> + 2<sup>-23</sup>) × 2<sup>-126</sup> (see [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2%5E-17%2B2%5E-23)*2%5E-126)). Adding a newline produces

```
00000000000000000000101001000001
```

which is 3.678⋅10<sup>-42</sup>.

Using doubles (`od -t fD`) adds another four bytes of zeroes to the front of the number, which doesn’t change the sign or exponent, and reduces the fraction further, which on top of the greater bias for doubles (-1022), results in the very small numbers you see (see [this other converter which uses doubles](http://weitz.de/ieee/)): “A” is (2<sup>-46</sup> + 2<sup>-52</sup>) × 2<sup>-1022</sup> (see [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2%5E-46%2B2%5E-52)*2%5E-1022)), “A” followed by a newline is (2<sup>-41</sup> + 2<sup>-43</sup> + 2<sup>-46</sup> + 2<sup>-52</sup>) × 2<sup>-1022</sup> (see [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2%5E-41%2B2%5E-43%2B2%5E-46%2B2%5E-52)*2%5E-1022)).